# Default views argument that can't be overriden?

Tags: 6, views

I have an argument comparing the current user ID to a field to determine what nodes to show, but all you have to do to impersonate another user is enter the argument in the address bar thus circumventing my default value. Is there a way to make an argument only ever use the default value and not exist as far as the address bar is concerned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the "User: Current" filter is not an option for you, then you can use a [hook_views_pre_execute()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions--views--docs--docs.php/function/hook_views_pre_execute/6) to modify the argument before the query is run.

In your custom module (assuming you have one argument):

```
function mymodule_views_pre_execute($view) {
    switch($view->name) {
        case 'name_of_view':
            global $user;
                if ($view->arg[0] != $user->uid) {
                    $view->build_info['query_args'][0] = $user->uid;
                }
            break;
    }
}
```

Even if a different argument is supplied in the URL, the current user's id will still be fed back into the view.

Comment: Sweet. And I suppose to simplify I could simply strip the argument entirely, so it always falls back on the default argument. It seems like there should be a checkbox that accomplishes this.

Comment: What actually works if you want the simplicity of forcing the default arg value to apply is to use hook_views_pre_view and set $args to null (or unsetting specific args in it).